# Objective C: Detecting touch events on UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am making a book application using a scrollview for paging but i am having problem detecting touch event on it all the touch events are not working. is there a way that i could implement touch event on scrollview?

Comment: are you using web view or scrollview to load the book?

Comment: What issue? [Questions](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) should be specific: describe exactly what you expect/want, and what actually happens, which includes any error messages. Include [minimal sample code](http://sscce.org/). Focus on one issue per question. Make sure the question hasn't been asked before posting, so you don't post a duplicate and add [noise](http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/S/signal-to-noise-ratio.html) to search results.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to build a book reading application.
I will suggest that rather than going with `UIScrollView` you can directly go for `UIPageViewController`

here are some referral link.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_a_Page_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_UIPageViewController

hope that help